# number of distinct values of x ....

Tags: trigonometry

Number of distinct values of $x$ where $\sin x=\frac x2$ where $x\in [0,\pi]$  degrees ?

Is it only at $0$ degrees? I would like to know the answer with a suitable explanation. That would be very helpful

Comment: Are you sure it's in _degrees_, not radians?

Comment: its in radians . what teh other point ? other than 0 ? why ? the values of x/2 only increases  right ? where is the other point ?

Comment: You don't need to know _where_ it is, only that it exists, and the intermediate value theorem tells you that. You can argue with derivatives that there are no more than two solutions. Also, in your question you say that it is degrees, you should change that by clicking the "edit" button below your question.